# Why squaring the multiplier in a Rank Order scoring

Tags: descriptive-statistics

I wanted to ask you about a rank-order scoring technique. It seems to make sense but I am not sure that I understand the reason for squaring. It must take into account the fact that there were a total number of choices and respondents selected one or more of those totals into the top 1,2 or 3. A rank order scale’s scores are weighted scores in which items selected first receive a higher value than the next ones in the list. This value is exponential and depends on the number of selections in your rank order scale. In your reports the percentage of all of these values (compared to the total) is shown.
For example:
There are 6 answer options from which your respondents need to select their top 3:

The first selection will receive a value of 36 (6²), the second 25 (5²) and the third 16 (4²). The values per response option are added together for all respondents and subsequently the percentages are calculated, which you also see in your chart.